# React native material dropdown - How to render the text based on dropdown value

Tags: react-native

Hi I'm new to react native. I'm using react-native-material-dropdown.I want to change the text content based on the drop down  value. By default my text content is empty and dropdown value also empty. When onChangeText function is triggers the text content should change based on selected drop down value.

Comment: Can you add some code to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post some of your code to get more accurate answers.

Meanwhile, please checkout the example code below with Dropdown example. Take a notice that dropdown's value is set to selectedCity `value={this.state.selectedCity}` and it is the same value manipulated when **`onChangeText`** triggers `this.setState`

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Dropdown } from 'react-native-material-dropdown';

export default class DropDownEx extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            cityData: [{
                value: 'City1',
                id: '123',
                otherData: 'descr1'
              }, {
                value: 'City2',
                id: '234',
                otherData: 'descr2'
              }, {
                value: 'City3',
                id: '345',
                otherData: 'descr3'
            }],
            selectedCity: ""
        };
    }

render() {
    return (

    <Dropdown
        label='City'
        data={this.state.cityData}
        value={this.state.selectedCity}
        containerStyle={{borderColor: "gray", borderWidth: 0.5, borderRadius: 5, height: 50}}
        inputContainerStyle={{ borderBottomColor: 'transparent', paddingTop: 10, paddingLeft: 10 }}
        onChangeText={(city) => this.setState({selectedCity: city})}
     />

)}
}
```